# Unable to transform http response in mule

Tags: mule, mule-component

I have a mule workflow which calls oozies' http service to start a job but I need to store the job id given out by oozie in the database. I implemented this but I am getting an exception once I transform the response from Oozie .

Cannot apply transformation. Payload is ReleasingInputStream.

```
<mule xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:quartz="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm" xmlns:test="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz 

http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz/current/mule-quartz.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test/3.6/mule-test.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.6/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/3.6/mule-vm.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/3.6/mule-http.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd"
    version="EE-3.5.2">
<object-to-string-transformer name="httptoobj" />
            <http:http-response-to-object-transformer name="httptostring" />

<flow name="polling" doc:name="polling">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint repeatInterval="3000"
        startDelay="3000" jobName="couchbasePoller" doc:name="Quartz">
        <quartz:event-generator-job />
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <component doc:name="Java">
        <singleton-object
            class="com.xyz.alertcampaign.appworkflow.CouchbasePoller" />
    </component>

    <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        path="oozieQueue" doc:name="Trigger workflow" />

</flow>
<flow name="oozie-workflow-manager" doc:name="oozie-workflow-manager">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        path="oozieQueue" doc:name="VM" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"  address="http://localhost:8080" responseTransformer-refs="httptostring"    doc:name="HTTP" />  

        <object-to-string-transformer />
    <component doc:name="Java">
        <singleton-object
            class="com.xyz.alertcampaign.appworkflow.JobUpdater" />
    </component>
</flow>
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting ??

Comment: Could you please post the entire stack trace? Thanks.

Comment: Got it working . Not a problem with Mule.

Answer (score 1):

You are applying the inputstream to string transformer twice:

```
responseTransformer-refs="httptostring"
```

and here

```
<object-to-string-transformer />
```

Also I'm guessing that you have an incorrect transformer named `httptostring`. Remove it or just remove the `responseTransformer-refs`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Actually I was able to solve the exception but the actual problem was that the dummy http server was not writing a new line before payload. Mule is working great.